# Replace specific char in char *

Tags: c

I want to replace a certain char with a newline. Here is my code:

```
char *string = ReadResource(); //returns pointer to array using memcpy()
char *FinalString = string;   
for(int x=0; x< int(SizeOfRes); x++)
      {
          if (string[x] == char(84)) 
            FinalString[x] = HERE DO I WANT A NEWLINE;

          else 
            FinalString[x] = string[x];
      }
```

I know that `char *` is read-only since this is a pointer to an array stored in the memory so using `FinalString[x] = '\n';` doesn't work.

But I can't `strcpy()` the array either because it contains NULL bytes.

Is there a simple way to achieve this?

Comment: What do you mean you can't modify an array stored in memory? Why does it have embedded nulls? Post some more context, please

Comment: Well `ReadResource` reads a specific resource and stores it in the memory using `memcpy()`. Then I would like to scan the array for a specific char and replace it in the copy `FinalString`. The array contains null bytes because it is a file stored as a byte array.

Comment: Include that in the code, please... I see no reason for the string to be read-only because it is in memory. Everything would be read-only if that was the case

Comment: You got an error somewhere else, either in your code or in your thinking... No way to find it unless you include that information in your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `memcpy()` if your array contains `NULL` characters.

A basic program which works :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  char *cbuffer = "hello \x00world";
  char buffer[12];
  memcpy((void *)buffer, (void *)cbuffer, 12);
  buffer[2] = 'h';  
  ofstream ofs ("nullfile.bin", ios::binary);
  ofs.write(buffer,12);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Like I said, I did copy the whole array with `memcpy()`. However, when I use `FinalString[y] = '\n';` it doesn't work (no newline in the final string).

Comment: how do you know there is no newline? did you try to `printf` it?

Comment: Because I copied the array into a file using this: `ofstream ofs;
  ofs.open( "output.data", ios::out );
  ofs.write( FinalString, int(SizeOfRes) );    
  ofs.close();`  and there is no newline (I used a Hex-Editor).

Comment: @Lotzki don't forget to open it in `std::ofstream::binary` :-)